# Show a script only once per hour with cookies not working

Tags: php, cookies

Hi i have set this script only show once per hour like this:

```
if( isset( $_COOKIE['showstuff']  ) ) 
{ 
} 
else 
{ 
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="'.$urlpath.'footer.js"></script>';
    setcookie('showstuff', 'true', time()+3600);
}
```

It will only show that script if the cookie doesn't exist, the problem is that it always show it and always sets a new cookie, ignoring the `if( isset( $_COOKIE['showstuff']  ) )`

Comment: Have you looked at the [signature of `setcookie()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)? Looks to me like `setcookie('showstuff', time()+3600);` isn't doing what you meant it to do.

Comment: you could do this on the client side with pure javascript and without php.

Comment: Then what do you suggest?

Comment: Just like @JaredFarrish indicated, this is the intended functionality. You're setting the value of the cookie as the time, not the expiration date. You need to add another argument, `setcookie('showstuff', 'somevalue', time()+3600)` So that the expiration date is properly applied.

Comment: Did it like you said "`setcookie('showstuff', 'somevalue', time()+3600)`" and still won't work.

Comment: Cookies are odd beasts; probably, just read more on how they work in practice? There are path considerations (such as, setting it in one domain then not being accessible in a subdomain of the same domain). I would probably setup a test page and `print_r($_COOKIE)` to see what you're getting. In other words, debug by inspecting what the server is sending and then receiving.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie

Answer (score -1):

Approach without php using jquery and the jquery cookie plugin:

```
<script>
    (function () {
        if (!$.cookie('onceADay')) {
            $.cookie('onceADay', 'enabled', {expires: 1});
            $.getScript("footer.js");
        }
    }());
</script>
```

- http://jsfiddle.net/S8kx9/
- https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie
- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: But then they can't use the value of the cookie in PHP.

Comment: that is true. but in the php code example i see currently no value for this.

Comment: The answer is not jQuery.